# Trying to inject datapoints into iOS webView using highcharts

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, highcharts, uiwebview

While porting an android app to iOS we hit a barrier:
We have a UIwebView set up to run HighCharts (it works with their provided sample), but we can't figure out how to pass variables to Javascript in order to display real time changes. 
The android-equivalent of what we're trying to do is:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + "point = " + "[Date.UTC("
                    + mYear + "," + mMonth + "," + mDay + "," + hr
                    + "," + min + "," + sec + "),"
                    + value+ "];");
```

or another example:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + "var curve_name = " + "'Illuminance';" +
                    "var unit_of_meas = " + "'lx';" +
                    "var x_axis_title = " + "'Date';" +
                    "var y_axis_title = " + "'Illuminance (lx)';" +
                    "var plot_title = " + "'Illuminance data';" +
                    "var plot_subtitle = " + "'';")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIWebView` has a method called `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` that you can use to run a script. I think that you can also use it to just pass and initialize any variable that you like.